# Getting Object Object in Express while using POST method for node

Tags: node.js, json, express, postman

I am following course for learning node. In process of API creation I have got strange error that doesn't break my code but yet I am not able to get the required output. Please check the `code`below. I am using `Express V4` as the trainer recommended to use the same version as he was using. Now my `code`is exact same but `output`is not same. I am using `Postman` for this purpose, and the image of `Postman` is also attached.
The actual `output` was supposed to `post`the `data` into my `tours api` but its adding `"id": "[object Object]1"` Please someone explain me why is that error and how to resolve it. Thanks in advance.

```
const express = require('express');
 const fs = require('fs');
 const app = express();
 const port = 3000;

 app.use(express.json());

const tours = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/dev-data/data/tours-simple.json`));

app.get('/api/v1/tours', (req, res) => {
          res.status(200).json({
               stauts: 'success',
               results: tours.length,
               data: {
                    tours // this is same as tours: tours
               }
          })
});

app.post('/api/v1/tours', (req, res) => {
          // console.log(req.body);
          const newId = tours[tours.length - 1].id + 1;
          const newTour = Object.assign({id: newId}, req.body);
          tours.push(newTour);
          fs.writeFile(`${__dirname}/dev-data/data/tours-simple.json`, JSON.stringify(tours), err => {
               res.status(201).json({
                    status: 'success',
                    data: {
                         tour: newTour
                    }
               });
          })
          // res.send('Done');
})

 app.listen(port, () => {
          console.log(`Server is listening at port no ${port}`);
 });
```

[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Shquy.png)
[tours-simple.json file data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGyMO.png)

I tried simple `post` to my `api` but my `data` wasn't posted instead `"id": "[object Object]1"` was added.

Comment: What is `tours`? seems like `tours[foo]` returns an `object` and when you do `{...} + 1` it implicitly calls `toString()` on that object, which gives you `[Object object]` and then concatenates `1` to it, which results in the `'[object Object]1'` you are seeing

Comment: tours basically reads a file where my json data is stored and its parsed result is stored in the "tours" variable.

Comment: Well, then read my comment again, `tours` contains `object`s so when you do `tours[someindex] + 1` you are trying to add `1` to an object. That doesn't work, so it implicitly calls `toString`. You proably want `const newId = tours[...].id + 1`

Comment: BTW depending on the node version you are using, you can use [`Array::at`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at)  to get the last element of an array  `tours.at(-1)`

Comment: I got your point, but when I add const newId = tours[...].id + 1 even then it's concatenating.

Comment: Well, then `tours[...].id` probably is not a number ...

Answer (score 0):

In Postman change the request body format from body -> raw -> Javascript to body -> raw -> JSON, this will allow your server to parse the request data.

For the id, I'm not really sure what you are trying to do, tours[tours.length-1] is an object, if you would like to get the id of the last element in tours and increment it by 1 you should change it to this:

```
      const newId = tours[tours.length - 1].id + 1;
```

Comment: Thanks now my data has been inserted successfully but still "id": "[object Object]11" coming along.

Comment: did you change the newId line as showcased?

Comment: yes i did the way you showed me.

Comment: Could you show an example of the content of tours-simple.json ?

Comment: yes I have updated the post with the image of tours-simple.json Please have a look.